# ¿Cómo generar y proteger url del archivo?

Tags: mysqli, php7

¿Cómo puedo ocultar la **Urls** original del archivo? y a la vez generar **Urls** únicas de un solo uso o de una sola visita ejemplo:

**De:**

```
example.com/archivo/video.mp4
```

**A:**

```
example.com/files/videos/premium/782d1a1a7/a0a34c39995e1fa95efdbf5.mp4
```

**Urls** únicas

Es decir si el usuario ya visito la siguiente **Urls**

```
example.com/files/videos/premium/782d1a1a7/a0a34c39995e1fa95efdbf5.mp4
```

Mostrar un mensaje de error

> El enlace solicitado ha caducado.

La **Urls** ya visitada ya no este disponible y a la vez generar una nueva **Url** en la base de datos para así evitar que el enlace o los enlaces sean compartido.

La dirección de la **Urls** sera por medio de la base de datos, y así al visitar la **Url** del archivo crear un `Update` de la nueva url.

**Mi idea** tabla archive.sql

```
id          url_generate
1      a0a34c39995e1fa95efdbf5
```

Generador de la **Url PHP**

```
function generateRandomString($length = 100) { 
    return substr(str_shuffle("0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"), 0, $length); 
}

?>

<div><?php echo generateRandomString(); ?></div>
```

¿Me pueden explicar como plantear el código php?

Un ejemplo sencillo de cómo funcionaría.

Comment: J. Mick, me parece que desafortunadamente tu pregunta es muy amplia. El caso es que pueden existir varias formas de lograr este objetivo (aun cuando unas sean mejores, mas seguras o mas eficientes que otras), por lo que básicamente estas preguntando "¿como harian uds esto....?" Te invito a [edit] tu pregunta y presentar lo que al momento has intentando y con que problemas te has enfrentado. Si no te es posible esto, te recomiendo darte una vuelta por el [chat] y obtener ideas de alli y quizas borrar tu pregunta.

Comment: @Kenny La he editado, creo que si la realizo en dos partes la pregunta no sera muy amplia, es difícil crear preguntas bienvenidas. :)

Comment: Con un uuid y... _¿para qué quieres conservar la extensión?_

Comment: @toledano amigo la planteado a la imaginación pero la extensión no es importante en realidad porque la idea es proteger la url original y generar una tras otra por visita única, url de un solo uso, mirando bien puse de más la extensión :)

Comment: Nose si puedes o deseas usar javascript, pero una opcion podria ser usar javascript y crear url de tipo blob(youtube lo usa en sus archivos).

Comment: @juliocpiro amigo este es otro tema :)

Comment: Necesariamente quieres enmascarar la url o puede quedar algo asi http://localhost/url/descargararchivo.php?file=dgjkteshjktrhk

Comment: @juliocpiro Cualquier opción es buena amigo, siempre en cuando el enlace sea único es decir que sea valido solo una sola vez y crear uno nuevo después de su visita, algo así como funciona los servidores de archivo no se si has descargado un archivo en uno de estos servidores y luego ya no puedes descargar con el mismo enlace

Answer (score 4):

Primero, extrayendo la idea básica, el sistema tiene en algún lado un archivo al que se quiere dar un acceso selectivo a través de un identificador único que caduque cuando se usa.

Segundo el identificador es parte de la Url.

Por la primera parte se necesita:

1) El archivo debe estar en un directorio no público de forma que no sea posible siquiera adivinar la url real. Pero php debe poder leer ese directorio para llegado el momento bajar el archivo.

Por ejemplo si el sitio está siendo servido de `/home/public_html`, los archivos a bajar se guardarían en `/home/archivos_privados`.

2) El sistema para dar acceso debe generar un string aleatorio, asociarlo al archivo físico y guardar esa asociación en algún lado hasta que se use. Puede ser en la sesión o en una tabla de la base de datos. A efectos de esta pregunta se usaría una tabla en la base de datos que permite persisitir el link incluso después de que la sesión se haya terminado.

Ejemplo: 
Para el archvivo `/home/archivos_privados/un_archivo.pdf` se genera un string `'XcV34kP56tF'` y se guardan en la tabla `tabla_asociaciones` en la base de datos.

La tabla `tabla_asociaciones` debe tener minimamente dos columnas:
`nombre_archivo_real`
`codigo_aleatorio`

Para insertar los datos:

```
$nombre_archivo = 'un_archivo.pdf';  
$codigo_aleatorio = 'XcV34kP56tF'
```

//SQL para insertar

```
Insert into tabla_asociaciones (nombre_archivo_real, codigo_aleatorio) 
values ($nombre_archivo, $codigo_aleatorio); //Al implementarlo usar prepared statements para evitar sql injection
```

Nota: *Como el path es igual para todos no es necesario guardarlo en la base, se puede pegar después.*

3) Ya con el string aleatorio puede armar la url y bajarla como link en la respuesta. La url debe tener una primera parte que identifique que se quiere descargar el archivo y la última parte del path, sería el identificador aleatorio.

Ejemplo de url:

```
http://www.misitio.com/descargar/XcV34kP56tF
```

*ACLARACIÓN en base al comentario de @J.Doe sobre ambiente de desarrollo:*

En caso de desarrollo local, en el archivo `hosts` tanto de linux como de Windows se puede relacionar a www.misitio.com con 127.0.0.1 que es la ip de localhost. Con este cambio y seteando el virtual host de XAMP a www.misition.com, podemos desarrollar localmente usando el FQDN.
Para ir al sitio real en iternet, después, solo hay que comentar la linea del archivo con #.

Para la segunda parte:

1) Se implementa un `rewrite rule` (por ejemplo en el .htaccess de Apache) que reconoce la primera parte del path del request que indica bajar un archivo, entonces aplica la regla que toma la parte del identificador aleatorio, y redirige al programa php que va a hacer la bajada, agregando la parte aleatoria como un paramétro del request.

Siguiendo el ejemplo, el rewrite rule, reconoce el patrón del path 'descargar/' seguido de la porción del path que tiene la asociación al archivo real. Y para poder usar este último como parámetro lo capturamos en un grupo.

Reconoce: `http://www.misitio.com/descargar/XcV34kP56tF`
Y guarda como grupo 1: `XcV34kP56tF`

Finalmente redirige a la nueva url:

```
http://www.misitio.com/descargar_archivo.php?archivo=XcV34kP56tF
```

En el archivo `.htaccess` se agregan las siguientes líneas par lograr esto:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^descargar\/(.+)$ http://misitio.com/descargar_archivo.php?archivo=$1 [R=301,L]
```

2) El programa descargar_archivo.php decodifica el id aleatorio que le llega como parámetro usando la asociación que estaba hecha de antemano en la tabla, y procede a descargar el archivo leyéndolo con su nombre real.

El programa en nuestro ejemplo sería `descargar_archivo.php` y el parámetro `archivo`.

**descargar_archivo.php** (Pseudocodigo para mostrar la lógica relevante)

```
$llave_al_archivo = $_GET['archivo'];

<Sanitizar $llave_llave_al_archivo>

//Buscar en la base de datos el archivo real
Select nombre_archivo_real 
from tabla_asociaciones 
where codigo_aleatorio = $llave_al_archivo;

if(resultado_query !== false){
    $nombre_real = resultado_query['nombre_archivo_real'];
    $archivo_real_con_path = '/home/archivos_privados/' . $nombre_real
    if(file_exists($archivo_real_con_path) === true){
        header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
        header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=' . $nombre_real);
        header('Pragma: no-cache');
        readfile($archivo_real_con_path);

        //Correr query para eliminar la asociación de forma que no se pueda volver a usar

        delete from tabla_asociaciones 
        where codigo_aleatorio = $llave_al_archivo;

    }else{
        //Reportar error interno, quizás el archivo existía y lo borraron.
    }    

}else{
  //Reportar error archivo no existe o ya fue bajado.
}
```

3) Una vez descargado el archivo, el programa elimina la asociación de la tabla de la base de datos. Por lo tanto si se vuelve a utilizar ya no encontrará el archivo y dará ese link como inválido y devolvería un mensaje de error en el response.

Comment: @Jaun El concepto es bueno, Pero creo que el ejemplo complica a un desarrollador cuando su servidor es `localhost` todos los trabajos se los realiza como prueba primeramente desde un servidor local, antes de subir el proyecto al servidor, creo que una solución es crear una carpeta privada con htaccess  en el mismo directorio donde se encuentra el proyecto, otro punto es que la **Url** generada al nuevo archivo debe ser por medio de la base de datos, actualizar una nueva después de que se haya visitado es lo que se da entender en la pregunta.

Comment: @J.Doe 1) La complicación es la misma si el servidor es remoto o seteado en tu máquina local con un XAMP. Hacer esto tiene su complejidad. 2) Si no es posible colocar el archivo fuera del document root por las políticas del hosting, la alternativa de usar una carpeta protegida con .htaccess es factible, aunque de ser posible sería mejor la primera solución. 3) La solución que plantié da las dos alternativas, o usar un array en la sesión o usar una tabla de la base de datos. Para la pregunta coincido que sería la opción de la base de datos.

Comment: @J.Doe Edité la respuesta acotándola a la solución con base de datos y agregué información adicional para desarrollar localmente con el FQDN real.

Comment: @Juan La documentación amigo es perfecta, pero me podrías ayudar con un ejemplo sencillo de como plantear la incógnita, estoy perdido, de poder generar código aleatoria y de insertar el registro perfecto hasta ahí pero de ahí no puedo avanzar.

Comment: Agregué bastante pseudo código y código como para que puedas atar las piezas. Si algo no queda claro avisame. También cabe aclarar que los pasos 1, 2 y 3 hasta que se devuelve el link ocurren como parte de un programa php que termina bajando el link como parte del html que devuelve como response.

Comment: @Juan en el ejemplo amigo, la consulta en el ejemplo toca añadirle las comillas o como lo has implementado también funciona disculpa mi curiosidad, que función cumple esto amigo `<Sanitizar $llave_llave_al_archivo>` y que dato contiene `$llave_al_archivo` me imagino que `$llave_llave_al_archivo` que se encuentra en `sanitizar` está demás una llave debe ser así verdad $llave_al_archivo

Comment: @Juan tengo problemas, no acabo de comprender lo e implementado de la siguiente manera  [https://ideone.com/5nS5cB](https://ideone.com/5nS5cB) tengo una carpeta en `localhost` llamada **url** dentro de la carpeta url e creado la nueva carpeta llamada **privados** y dentro de la carpeta se encuentra el archivo `archivo.pdf` he accedido `http://localhost/url/descargararchivo.php` y me ejecuta el siguiente error `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '<' in C:\xampp\htdocs\url\descargararchivo.php on line 7` la linea 7 se refiere **a:** `<Sanitizar $llave_al_archivo>`

Comment: @Juan y el archivo del enlace de descarga como lo acciono.

Comment: Las consultas a la base de datos están como pseudocódigo, vos las tenes que implementar con mysqli o PDO. Lo mismo el código php no está completo, es para orientarte. Sanitizar una variable significa asegurarte que tenga un valor esperado para el dato que esperás recibir.  $llave_al_archivo contiene código aleatorio que sirve de llave (key o índex) para llegar al nombre real del archivo. El enlace de descarga lo accionás haciendo click sobre el link una vez renderizada la página.

Answer (score -1):

Se me ocurre algo así:
1. Sólo usuarios autenticados pueden descargar archivos, en el caso se pasen el link del archivo y aquel que quiera descargar no tiene un usuario, el sistema lo redirige al login.
2. Crear permisos por usuario para cada archivo.
3. Crear un middleware que valide los permisos antes de descargar.
4. Puedes usar laravel para todo esto.

Answer (score -2):

**Tablas Relacionales**

No creo que sea necesario enmascarar la url para evitar la descarga de archivos, podrías simplemente implementar una tabla de relaciones entre los archivos y tus usuarios y desde ahí validar que página puede acceder y a cual no.

Con esto incluso puedes manejar mejor las ventanas de tiempo que tendría cada usuario agregando fechas de acceso.

Tabla Relacional

**UsuarioID | ProductoID | Status | DatetoEnd**

Con esto solo permitirías el llamado a la página solicitada después de haber validado el estatus en la tabla desde los cookies de autenticación.

Comment: Pero que pasa si el usuario obtiene la url de descarga del archivo, si desde el navegador al descargar un archivo se puede ver la ruta de descarga del archivo, Puedes ayudarme con un ejemplo amigo.

Comment: Usas una pagina tipo download.php y ahi validas si el usuario esta logoneado y debe poder descargar el archivo, algo así                                              if($usuariopago === true) {                               
  $filename = 'Archivosecreto.pdf'; //Lo que se debe displayar
  $file = './download/pdf/secretlink.pdf';      
  header('Content-type: application/pdf');
  header('Content-Disposition: inline; filename="'.$filename.'"');
  header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
  @readfile($file);
  exit;
}